# MYSQL include columns w. a count of 0

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

So here is my query :

```
SELECT
  COUNT( user_id ) AS `Records` ,
  DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `tstamp` ) ) AS `Date`
FROM `user`
WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME('tstamp') >= '2014-11-00'
GROUP BY DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `tstamp` ) )
LIMIT 200
```

The issue is that it only returns rows where count of records greater than 0. Is there a way to include dates where the count = 0?

Comment: you need to have a calendar table and do left join with calendar table to get rows with zero count.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your own calendar table in a subquery

```
SET @start_date = '2014-11-01';
SELECT MyData.dt,IFNULL(MyData.Records,0) Records FROM
(
    SELECT dt FROM
    (SELECT num,(@start_date + INTERVAL num DAY) dt FROM
    (SELECT h*100+t*10+u num FROM
    (SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) A,
    (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B,
    (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) C) AA) AAA
    WHERE dt <= DATE(NOW())
    ORDER BY num
) Calendar LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(user_id) AS `Records` ,
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tstamp`)) dt
    FROM `user`
    WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME('tstamp') >= '2014-11-00'
    GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tstamp`))
    LIMIT 200
) MyData USING (dt);
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT : This calendar subquery is only good 999 days back.

You can extend back 9999 days like this

```
SET @start_date = '2014-11-01';
SELECT MyData.dt,IFNULL(MyData.Records,0) Records FROM
(
    SELECT dt FROM
    (SELECT num,(@start_date + INTERVAL num DAY) dt FROM
    (SELECT th*1000+h*100+t*10+u num FROM
    (SELECT 0 th UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Z,
    (SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) A,
    (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B,
    (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
    SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) C) AA) AAA
    WHERE dt <= DATE(NOW())
    ORDER BY num
) Calendar LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(user_id) AS `Records` ,
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tstamp`)) dt
    FROM `user`
    WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME('tstamp') >= '2014-11-00'
    GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`tstamp`))
    LIMIT 200
) MyData USING (dt);
```

Comment: You are kind of amazing sir. idk if it exactly solves my existing problem , but it gives me some ideas on how I could do things a bit different. Thank you for taking the time to put this together.

Comment: I am going to update my answer to make it display zero (I forgot that part)